# Why are these variables written before being assigned to anything?

Tags: php, class, variables

I'm learning PHP so bear with me. Both of these classes set either a public or private variable, before it is used. Why is this?

```
  class test {
    public $name; // called here
    public function __construct ($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
     }
  }
  $testing = new test('Hello');
  echo $testing->name;
```

and:

```
class db_link {
  private $link; // called here
  public function __construct ($database_name) {
   $link = mysql_connect ("localhost", "your_user_name", "your_password");
   mysql_select_db ($database_name, $link);
   $this -> link = $link;
   }
  function query ($sql_query) {
   $result = mysql_query ($sql_query, $this -> link);
   return $result;
   }
  function __destruct() {
   mysql_close ($this -> link);
   }
  }
 $db = new db_link ("MyDB")
 $result = $db->query ("Select * from MyTable")
```

Comment: The question is not clrear

Comment: Sorry, edited it. I meant the variables are set before being used.

Comment: They're properties of the class and not necessarily to be viewed as variables. Call them what you will though. You can declare them as well, but as you gain experience you'll see how classes tend to be constructed.

Comment: "variables are set before being used" --- that's how you usually program. You cannot set variable *after* it's being used, it makes no sense

Answer (score 2):

When you are declaring a class as in your example, you are setting up the skeleton for not only what it is, but what it CAN be. The declaration should really include anything and everything that will ever be inside the object - whether or not it will always be used.

In this case it's like saying the object *can* have hands and fingers, but not all the instances of the object will actually have them.

Although PHP allows some really interesting code (like creating a new property the first time that a value is assigned to it) even if it isn't part of the original object, it's generally considered bad form - and makes it almost impossible to track down errors in the code later.

I can't more strongly suggest only ever using properties that are declared and not just adding things on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

This is to initialize the variable and explicitly set it to public or private so you don't have to hunt through the code for the information.

Variable initialization is a common programming practice in many languages.

Comment: well... technically ALL languages require variable initialisation...

Comment: What is it called when the assignment includes the initialization?

Answer (score 1):

They're declaring these variables to be members of the class. If you declare a variable inside of a function, it only exists within the functions 'namespace.' Once that function ends, the variable is deleted. Declaring external to functions allows the variables to inhabit the class' namespace, which means they are accessible to any functions that are methods of the class.

Quick Edit: this also means that the variables will be inherently tied to the class so instances of the class will contain those variables allow them to be accessible and modifiable through accessors and mutators. All in all, it's a very sound method both for reliability and accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're asking. This is related to Scope.

The variables that are passed to the constructor are available only until the constructor function completes. To register the variables as members of the object you need to assign them to a parameter of the class. Hence:

```
public $name; // called here
public function __construct ($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
 }
```

You can name the variable that is passed to the constructor anything you like (e.g. `__construct($argument); $this->name = $argument;`).

You're really just telling the constructor to expect a variable when the object is created. It is a common convention to name the variables passed to the constructor the same of the property name to help with readability, but there is no name conflict as the constructor variable does not share scope with the object parameters. the logic of doing this is that it is easier to understand where the variables passed to the constructor are going to be assigned.

so `__construct($name)` and `public $name;` ($this->name) are two completely separate pieces of memory .

I hope this helps. I remember what it was like trying to get my head around things like this.

Comment: Thanks. So what could the logic be in this example, that allows the same variable name for two different uses?

Comment: Well. You can name the variable that is passed to the constructor anything you like (e.g. __construct($argument); $this->name = $argument), you're really just telling the constructor to expect a variable when the object is created. It is a common convention to name the variables passed to the constructor the same of the property name to help with readability, but there is no name conflict as the constructor variable does not share scope with the object parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your member variable anywhere, e.g. this will work:

```
class test {
    public function __construct ($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
     }
    public $name; // member variable $name
  }

  $testing = new test('Hello');
  echo $testing->name;
```

However it is much more clear if you declare your member variables at the top of the class. Why? Because it is just trivial to be able to clearly see what variables a class is using...

Comment: Does having the function parameter as `$name` affect the `public $name` in anyway?

Comment: no it does not, you use the `$this` keyword to reference the class level var

Comment: Thanks. So what could the possible logic be in this example, that allows the same variable name for two different variables?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. But in the example above, there are two different variables : a member variable (or call it instance variabale) and a local variable of a function (which is __construct here). If you don't understand how these two variables are different, then you need to learn more about Object oriented programming: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php
(Sorry if I misunderstood you)